# Repeat Footer on all page at the bottom while printing

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to print a web page that contains a footer.
I am able to display footer in all pages but on the last page if the content is less then my footer goes to the end of the content..

on the last page my footer does not appear at the bottom.

here is my CSS

```
@media print {

.rptHeader { display: table-header-group; }

.rptFooter { display: table-footer-group;bottom: 10;}    
}
```

![Here is my last page how it looks...Please help me][1]

Comment: i am not able to attach image

Comment: Can you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and mock up your issue?